# How do i get count of unacked messages from rabbitmq using java code

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp

I got the total messagecount in the queue but i am unable to count ready and unacked messages.

Comment: I am not able to manage plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the count of unacked message using java (I mean programmatically).

However you can get it :

- Using `rabbitmqctl` command line
- Using Rest API

You can get more info here : http://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html

Comment: How? I don't see the option to show unacknowledged counts in rabbitmqctl using `list_queues` is there a different command?

Comment: There is a `messages_unacknowledged` option in `list_queues`, see doc: https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmqctl.8.html